# Are all collisions involving photons and electrons elastic?

Tags: photons, electrons, atomic-physics, scattering

In my textbook it asks me to calculate the energy gained by an electron that scatters an incoming x ray through a given angle.

Using the Compton scattering equation you can work out the change in the x ray's energy. The difference is given to the electron as its gain in KE.

My question is : is it possible for the electron to gain less than the photons change in energy?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering#Inverse_Compton_scattering

Comment: energy and momentum conservation laws are strict. in this two body interaction, photon electron, what the photon loses has to be balanced by the gain of the electron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Total energy is always conserved, even in inelastic collisions. Some energy might 'disappear' because the internal energy of one or both particles changes and this is not obvious from observing the motion of the particles. Such collisions are called 'inelastic.' For example, in a collision between molecules the internal vibrations or the rotation of one or both molecules might change. Or in a collision between atoms there might be a temporary change in the energy levels which electrons occupy within each atom.

Electrons do not have any internal structure so they cannot store energy internally. They have no energy levels as atoms do, and they cannot rotate to store rotational KE.

The total energy lost by the photon must equal that gained by the electron, and *vice versa* if a moving electron is slowed by a collision with a photon.

Comment: A electron-photon reaction that included an on-shell pair-production could reasonably be characterized as "inelastic", though in many practical cases the cause of the inelasticity would be rather obvious.

Comment: If the electron spin is flipped in the interaction, it will emit a photon.  This should be figured into the answer.